# Set Title in ActionBar - Screen with Tabgroups - Titanium Alloy

Tags: android, android-actionbar, titanium-alloy

I'm using Titanium version 3.1.3 and alloy framework. I implemented the action bar in my app; but in the screen with tab groups in it, the title is missing from action bar. Only the icon is getting displayed in it. From this - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-11645, I can see that, this is fixed in SDK version: 3.1.0.v20130320190115. But still, I'm not able to figure out why.

I tried setting the title of action bar through code like this

```
var actionBar;
if (Ti.Platform.osname === "android") {
        if (! $.tab.activity) {
            Ti.API.error("Can't access action bar on a lightweight window.");
        } else {
            actionBar = $.tab.getActivity().actionBar;
            if (actionBar) {
                alert("true");
                //actionBar.title = "TITLE";
                actionBar.setTitle("TITLE");
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get access to some ActionBar methods and properties, like the title, your code needs to be run [after the tabgroup is opened](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_Action_Bar-section-36735509_AndroidActionBar-OtherActionBarFeatures).

In your view, you can add event listener like this:

```
<TabGroup onOpen="doOpen">
    ....
</TabGroup>
```

Then in your controller, put your code in the callback:

```
function doOpen(){
    var actionBar;
    if (Ti.Platform.osname === "android") {
        if (! $.tab.activity) {
           Ti.API.error("Can't access action bar on a lightweight window.");
        } else {
            actionBar = $.tab.getActivity().actionBar;
            if (actionBar) {
                alert("true");
                //actionBar.title = "TITLE";
                actionBar.setTitle("TITLE");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested your code in the open event callback using SDK 3.2.1, and it worked fine.

[Here](https://github.com/adampax/AlloyActionJackson/blob/master/app/controllers/index.js) is another example for modifying the ActionBar title.